# Need help hiding "Close As Won" button using Ribbon Workbench when "Document Status" field = "Ready to Export"

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm-ribbon-workbench

I am trying to hide the "Close As Won" button on my CRM Opportunity form using the Ribbon Workbench when "Document Status" field = "Ready to Export". However, I can't seem to get it to actually hide.  Is this possible?  If so, how?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Definitely you can hide this button.

You need Ribbon workbench, customize command for Close as won button.

Below image shows new enable rule. To give you example, I will hide close as won button when Status of Opp is "In Progress", if it is on hold or something else it will show close as won button.
Invert rule is used because it will enable only when status!=1

[image]

If you see below for a command I have added new Enable Rule

[image]

Below 2 images shows when status is "In Progress" button is hidden and when "on hold" then button is shown.

[image]

[image]

Comment: ,,
Thanks for your reply.  Am I able to use a "Value rule" like you have for my Opportunity Scope field, which is an option set, or do I have to create a custom rule?

Comment: Sorry, I meant my "Document Status" field, which is a text field, not the Opportunity Scope field.

Comment: @TimG when you mean `Document Status`  field, not opportunity scope, do you mean in some related entity let's say for ex in related account or contact record?

Comment: No, the Document Status field is a text field in the Opportunity entity.

Comment: @TimG You can stil use Value rule, for ex: Doc status value is "Doc1" hide else don't hide same as Status field

Comment: No, I am still unable to get it to work.  I created a value rule under "Enable Rules", set "Invert Result" to true, Set the field to new_QW_DocumentStatus, and set the value to "Ready To Export".  I also added the rule to the Mark As Won command.  However, I notice the button is now not showing up regardless of whether or not the Document Status field is set to "Ready To Export".  Any idea why this may be happening?

Comment: Still having trouble with this... any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you try again from scratch, remove any enable rule or anything for this button and see if you atleast can view it, later on try using JavaScript for enable rule. Try fetching data in JavaScript and based on it return true or false for your JavaScript function